# How can I use half floats with CoreML neural nets?

Tags: coreml

I have converted a Keras model to CoreML. I want to make sure that CoreML uses half floats and not full floats for all its textures. How can I do this?

Updated:
How can I make sure that the output of the network is half-float or at least Float (or any other type) and not Double?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything for this if you run the CoreML model on the GPU. MPS (Metal Performance Shaders) will use half floats automatically. You can see this if you run a GPU Frame Capture on your CoreML model.

I wrote a blog post about how CoreML works under the hood, that actually demonstrates it uses half floats: http://machinethink.net/blog/peek-inside-coreml/

Comment: Could you point me to where in the blog post you show that (very nice post btw)? I cant find it.

Comment: Look at the screenshots from the GPU Frame Capture. It says that the textures are RGBA16Float.

Comment: @twerdster - Also, additional evidence for this is present within [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MetalImageRecognition/Listings/MetalImageRecognition_Inception3Net_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017385-MetalImageRecognition_Inception3Net_swift-DontLinkElementID_5) where in the `getLabel()` method they have to convert raw bytes from an MPSImage from Float16 to Float32 in order to work with them. That shows that they always expect these to be half floats.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans In your code here: https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph/commit/a7db77b6ad3827323e53100f78e24e435d815b93 it casts the output MLMultiArray to a Double and then later reads as Floats. What is the thinking behind this? Are the outputs half floats/ floats/ doubles? Im confused.

Comment: Core ML converts the output from the neural network to doubles. (Apparently you can change this in the mlmodel file.) The reason I cast to floats is that the code I used to process the results came from another project and there I used floats. ;-) Could also have used doubles there. But internally Core ML appears to use half floats if the model runs on the GPU.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Okay. Thanks for clearing that up. Could you include in your answer the line that demonstrates how to ask the mlmodel file to output int8 or float instead of Doubles?

Comment: There was a post on the Apple Developer Forums that shows how to do this, but I don't have a link handy. https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/system-frameworks/machine-learning

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans the answer is outdated. Now, the `compute_precision` parameter can he used to specify the precision in which the model weights are stored and the precision for the computations.